# When installing OneDrive on Windows 7, Windows tells me to uninstall the previous version. I am unable to uninstall the previous version

Tags: windows-7, installation, uninstall, onedrive

This is on a work computer. For some reason they decided to recreate all of our user accounts. I needed to reinstall all the software I use.

When I try to install OneDrive with OneDriveSetup.exe from Microsoft, this message pops up,

[image]

Which translates to,

> **A new version of OneDrive is being installed.**
>
> In order to install this version, the previous version must be uninstalled.

However, OneDrive isn't listed in the Program and Features dialog. It also isn't showing up in CCleaner's uninstall list.

Is there a "OneDrive Removal Tool" or something I can run to get rid of whatever Remnants of a previous OneDrive install are on this computer?

Comment: It'll be less of a headache if I can figure this out myself. 

Without going into details the short version is: cultural reasons, language barrier, and questionably competent "IT department" consisting of one person. Even if I can convince someone to help me, they may not even be able to re-image the computer.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found something that worked for me.

OneDrive is installed to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive

Once in that folder I navigated to the "Update" folder and ran the copy of "OneDriveSetup.exe" that's there.

For some reason, *that one* ran and that installed and set up OneDrive on my computer, despite the fact that the file I downloaded from Microsoft bearing the exact same name did not work.

I don't really know *why* that worked, but that's what I ended up doing.